# SQL join and insert new column as % parent total - syntax error in FROM clause

Tags: excel, vba, join, adodb

have the following vba code to query from excel worksheet (worksheet name is Structre) using sql but im running into "syntax error in FROM clause"

```
Dim MyConnect As String
Dim MyRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Dim MySQL As String

MyConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
           "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
           "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0" 
mysql2 = SELECT [Structure$].c, [Structure$].a, [Structure$].b from [Structure$] _
join(SELECT a, sum(c) as csum FROM [Structure$] group by a) tmp on tmp.a=[Structure$].a

Set MyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
MyRecordset.Open mysql2, MyConnect, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

 ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
 ActiveSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset MyRecordset
```

---

```
 a           b      c       Desired col: weights
Finance      1      123     123/(123+345+456)
Finance      2      345     345/(123+345+456)
Finance      3      456     456/(123+345+456)
Operation    1      789     789/(789+12)
Operation    2      12      12/(789+12)
BD           1      111     111/(111+222)
BD           2      222     222/(111+222)
```

what i would like to do is from the table (with columns a,b,c), retrieve them and insert a new column weights as the c/sum(groupby(a)), as shown in the table above. Not sure where im going wrong (still newbie to sql).

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the excel formula instead of writing vba code.

Following will calculate the sum (group by a) which you can use in E column

```
=IF(A2=A1,SUMIF(A:A,A2,C:C),SUMIF(A:A,A2,C:C))
```

And then you can use following in D column

```
=C2/E2
```

You can also combine both the formulas.

```
=C2/IF(A2=A1,SUMIF(A:A,A2,C:C),SUMIF(A:A,A2,C:C))
```

Comment: hi thanks. i know it can be easily done via excel formula but i am currently learning sql and thought it would be a good practice..